# Blender 2.83 - water flow

Tags: physics

I'm trying to find any video or a website on making water flow (simple outflow from a sewage pipe as it is for a game, it then goes to a river or lake so i probably don't need any sink or ground for water to fall into) for Blender 2.83.
Anything is pre-2.83 and in that version baking is gone. I've found a tip in the comments [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nANhiGqYS5c) but that doesn't work either.

Anyone knows where to look for, or would that be better to go back to previous version? I don't suppose it would be back in 2.90, is it?

(and honestly - tags are more frustrating than helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to Cache inside the physics settings. Switch the Cache Type to modular. Replay (the default cache type in 2.83+) will allow the simulation to run when you are playing the animation, modular actually bakes it onto the disk.  You can also switch it to Final to bake everything at once, but note that final bake.

A lot of people have this problem when they watch tutorials done in a previous release of blender and don't know what to do because some things changed. Reading the documentation should clear everything up. It is written very clearly. https://docs.blender.org/manuel/en/latest